# Is in_array or similar possible within an if statement?

Tags: twig

I am using [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) as a templating engine. However, I ran in a situation which definitely must be accomplishable in a simpler way than I have found.

What I have right now is this:

```php
{% for myVar in someArray %}    
    {% set found = 0 %}
    {% for id, data in someOtherArray %}
         {% if id == myVar %}
              {{ myVar }} exists within someOtherArray.
              {% set found = 1 %} 
         {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if found == 0 %}
        {{ myVar }} does not exist within someOtherArray.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What I am looking for is something more like this:

```php
{% for myVar in someArray %}    
    {% if myVar is in_array(array_keys(someOtherArray)) %}
       {{ myVar }} exists within someOtherArray.
    {% else %}
       {{ myVar }} does not exist within someOtherArray.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this which I haven't seen yet?

If I need to create my own extension, how can I access `myVar` within the test function?

Answer (score 535, accepted):

You just have to change the second line of your second code-block from:

```php
{% if myVar is in_array(array_keys(someOtherArray)) %}
# or
{% if myVar in someOtherArray|keys %}
```

[`in`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#containment-operator) is the containment-operator, and [`keys`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/keys.html), is a filter that returns an arrays keys.

Comment: If you want to achieve the same as in_array() in PHP, ommit the keys filter

Comment: + 1 And also the negation is `{% if item not in array %}` and not `{% if not _entry.id in array %}`, so it's different from this `{% if not var is null %}`.

Comment: You can also use defined : `{% if someOtherArray.myVar is defined %}` (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html)

Comment: Here's a Twig fiddle to play with of the complete solution based upon the OP's code and the code in this answer: https://twigfiddle.com/0b5crp

Answer (score 138):

Just to clear some things up here. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7460598/17726418) does not do the same as PHP `in_array`.

To do the same as PHP `in_array`, use the following expression:

```php
{% if myVar in myArray %}
```

If you want to negate this, you should use this:

```php
{% if myVar not in myArray %}
```

Answer (score 45):

Try this:

```php
{% if var in ['foo', 'bar', 'beer'] %}
   {{ var }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 11):

Another example following @jake stayman:

```php
{% for key, item in row.divs %}
    {% if (key not in [1,2,9]) %} // eliminate element 1,2,9
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Though the above answers are right, I found a more user-friendly approach while using the ternary operator.

```
{{ attachment in item['Attachments'][0] ? 'y' : 'n' }}
```

If someone needs to work through `foreach`, then:

```
{% for attachment in attachments %}
    {{ attachment in item['Attachments'][0] ? 'y' : 'n' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Don't know why this answer gets no upvotes.
While this one-liner is the smallest and perfect code you can have nowadays.
For example using `{{ item.value in cfg.static_site ? ' checked="checked"' : '' }}` in a for loop (checking if a specific item exists in that array) will check that item.

Answer (score 3):

```php
{% for user in users if user.active and user.id not 1 %}
   {{ user.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

More info: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Comment: Adding an if condition on a for tag is deprecated in Twig 2.10. Use a filter filter or an “if” condition inside the “for” body instead (if your condition depends on a variable updated inside the loop). https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/deprecated.html#tags

Answer (score 1):

The below, without `keys`, helps me.

```php
{% if myVar in myArray %}
```

Comment: yep, or even {% if 5 in [3,5] %}

Answer (score 0):

Here's one to complete the answers with all the possibilities of Twig these days:

To achieve something like this:

```
{% for myVar in someArray %}    
    {% if myVar in someOtherArray|keys %}
       {{ myVar }} exists within someOtherArray.
    {% else %}
       {{ myVar }} doesn't exist within someOtherArray.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

<sup>(https://twigfiddle.com/0b5crp)</sup>

You could also use [array mapping](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/map.html) and have the following one-liner:
<sup>(Twig >= 1.41 or >= 2.10 or any 3.x version)</sup>

```
{{ someArray|map(myVar => myVar ~ (myVar not in someOtherArray|keys ? ' doesn\'t') ~ ' exists within someOtherArray.')|join('\n') }}
```

Which outputs something quite similar.

Also see this Twig fiddle: https://twigfiddle.com/dlxj9g